# Why does the server can't find my build.js file?

Tags: vue.js, heroku, deployment, server

I am trying to deploy Vue + Flask application to Heroku

On the server side the command `npm run build` is run and the `dist` folder appears containing `index.html` & `build.js` inside.
In the `index.html` I have `<script src="/dist/build.js"></script>`
But when I try to open my app all I get is blank empty page.
In the logs I see:

```
2020-06-29T17:04:23.211646+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/dist/build.js" host=myapp.herokuapp.com request_id=some-request-id fwd="some-ip" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=10ms status=404 bytes=400 protocol=https
```

Why can't the server find the `build.js` inside the `dist`, even though I can see that it is there?

Comment: Seems a problem of relative path

Comment: @Raffobaffo agree, I tried to specify the relative path in `webpack.config.js` in the _output.publicPath_ but nothing has changed

Comment: What the output on console?

Comment: @Raffobaffo what do you mean? The logs hasn't changed. Output of what command should I provide?
btw I recreated the project using this template https://github.com/swasher/flask-vue-heroku and deployed successfully

Comment: I meant browser console, but if you solved in another way, that's cool too :)